# Install Solar Light + Panel to side of house that has Vinyl Siding?

Tags: lighting, mounting, vinyl

I bought a [led solar motion activated light](https://sunforceproducts.com/products/100-led-triple-head-solar-motion-light/) and I am wondering what is the best way to install it on a house that has vinyl siding.

I seen a few possible ways

1. Drill holes directly into the vinyl and then add vinyl siding mounting block.
2. Get vinyl siding hooks and try to mount it that way.

For the first way I am unclear if I need to found a stud to install it on to or if I can choose anywher? If I need to find a stud how do I do this? Will a stud finder be able to go through the vinly?

For the second way. I am not sure if these hooks will be able to hold the light I linked too and where I live it can get extremely windy (and in the winter time snows) so it would need to stand up to elements.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the wall behind the vinyl, is it wood or stucco.

Comment: I think it is stucco.

Comment: A stud finder will work just fine through vinyl siding. It may, however, be quite confounded by the solid plywood or OSB that should be acting as sheathing for the outside of your house. However, that 1/2" to 3/4" sheathing should do just fine to hold up the light, especially since it's only 2lbs (<1kg).

Answer (score 0):

You will need 4 inch long wood screws.

Pre-drill through the vinyl and stucco but not further (about 1.5 inches deep.

When you screw in the 4 inch screws you will screw in the plywood boards (that are under your stucco)on your home.

That will hold almost anything.

Comment: Can you please expand to show how you come up with a 4" long screw? 1" for holding in the stud (deeper could hit electrical in an exterior wall), plus 1/2" for plywood sheathing. What is the other 2-1/2" for? Stucco can't be _that_ thick.

Comment: @FreeMan from lots of experience, 2-1/2 wont do it

Comment: Will I need to put a mounting block first?